# Google map is not opening and there are no error in console

Tags: google-maps

Google Map is not opening in the browser. and there is no errors in the console too. so i cant identify the issue & what iam doing wrong.  note: iam running in wamp server.

iam trying to add multiple markers on googlemaps using zoho crm record data. finally when i tried to do it in this way but i end up here like this. any help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Account Locations</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyB3pwJBXen9pXXXXXXXoeZOEYoPWsM">
    </script>     <!-- i used enabled geocoding apikey here -->
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map"></div>
</body>


<style type="text/css">
    html {
        height: 100%
    }  
    body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0
    }  
    #map-canvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
</style>


</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var delay = 100;
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 5,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    function geocodeAddress(address, next) {
        geocoder.geocode({
            address: address
        }, function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var p = results[0].geometry.location;
                var lat = p.lat();
                var lng = p.lng();
                createMarker(address, lat, lng);
            } else {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
                    nextAddress--;
                    delay++;
                } else {}
            }
            next();
        });
    }

    function createMarker(add, lat, lng) {
        var contentString = add;
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
            map: map,
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });

        bounds.extend(marker.position);

    }
    var locations = [
        'New Delhi, India',
        'Mumbai, India',
        'Bangaluru, Karnataka, India',
        'Hyderabad, Ahemdabad, India',
        'Gurgaon, Haryana, India',
        'Cannaught Place, New Delhi, India',
        'Bandra, Mumbai, India',
        'Nainital, Uttranchal, India',
        'Guwahati, India',
        'West Bengal, India',
        'Jammu, India',
        'Kanyakumari, India',
    ];
    var nextAddress = 0;

    function theNext() {
        if (nextAddress < locations.length) {
            setTimeout('geocodeAddress("' + locations[nextAddress] + '",theNext)', delay);
            nextAddress++;
        } else {
            map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
    }
    theNext();
</script>
```

[please refer this if any doubt, what will this code do](http://jsfiddle.net/P2QhE/6264/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `map` doesn't have a size.  Their is no CSS for `#map`.  `#map-canvas` in your CSS should be `#map`.

**working code snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Account Locations</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js">
  </script>
  <!-- i used enabled geocoding apikey here -->
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map"></div>
</body>


<style type="text/css">
  html {
    height: 100%
  }
  
  body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0
  }
  
  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
</style>


</html>


<script type="text/javascript">
  var delay = 100;
  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 5,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);
  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

  function geocodeAddress(address, next) {
    geocoder.geocode({
      address: address
    }, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        var p = results[0].geometry.location;
        var lat = p.lat();
        var lng = p.lng();
        createMarker(address, lat, lng);
      } else {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OVER_QUERY_LIMIT) {
          nextAddress--;
          delay++;
        } else {}
      }
      next();
    });
  }

  function createMarker(add, lat, lng) {
    var contentString = add;
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
      map: map,
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.setContent(contentString);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    });

    bounds.extend(marker.position);

  }
  var locations = [
    'New Delhi, India',
    'Mumbai, India',
    'Bangaluru, Karnataka, India',
    'Hyderabad, Ahemdabad, India',
    'Gurgaon, Haryana, India',
    'Cannaught Place, New Delhi, India',
    'Bandra, Mumbai, India',
    'Nainital, Uttranchal, India',
    'Guwahati, India',
    'West Bengal, India',
    'Jammu, India',
    'Kanyakumari, India',
  ];
  var nextAddress = 0;

  function theNext() {
    if (nextAddress < locations.length) {
      setTimeout('geocodeAddress("' + locations[nextAddress] + '",theNext)', delay);
      nextAddress++;
    } else {
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }
  }
  theNext();
</script>
```